# How to run winget command and show its progress bar and size of update if it is inside a variable ( PowerShell )

Tags: powershell, winget

I am working on a PowerShell command that updates all my apps with one click but I ran into a problem
I stored the winget command inside a variable $upgradeResult
the code was `$upgradeResult=winget upgrade -u --id $($_.Id) --silent --accept-source-agreements`
I noticed that the code runs without displaying anything so I added `Write-Host $upgradeResult`
but there is an issue with the output it shows like this

```
    -     \     |                                                                                                                               -     \     |                                                                                                                           No available upgrade found. No newer package versions are available from the configured sources.
```

I don't know why it shows these characters     -     \     |   -     \     |

I tried `Invoke-Expression`
and I tried to add `| Out-String` after the code but nothing seems to work
it still shows these random characters    -     \     |   -     \     |

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the Microsoft.WinGet.Client PowerShell module. It's still in preview, but you're going to get better output objects.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.WinGet.Client/